# How to sort listview with listview items android?

Tags: android, arraylist, android-listview, android-adapter, android-listadapter

I have a listview which I populate from the database. The list shows available food with the following details:

1. The time of food preparation
2. Rating of restaurant
3. Lat/ Long of restaurant
4. Quantity of food.

Now I want to sort the listview based on these four items. I am using a `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>` and an adapter extending the baseadapter.

I have seen many answers on SO with Collections.sort but I fail to implement it in my code.

**NOTE**: I do not have a datamodel defined for the AvailableFood object to populate the arrayList.
Here is my code:

**AvailableFood.java**

```
public class AvailableFood extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_available_food, container, false);

        mBottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
                switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
                    case R.id.nav_sort:
                        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(getContext(), rootview.findViewById(R.id.nav_sort));
                        MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
                        inflater.inflate(R.menu.sort_menu, popup.getMenu());
                        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
                                switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
                                    case R.id.sort_recent: sortAvailableFood("Time");
                                        break;
                                    case R.id.sort_qty: sortAvailableFood("Qty");
                                        break;
                                    case R.id.sort_rating: sortAvailableFood("Rating");
                                        break;
                                    case R.id.sort_distance: sortAvailableFood("Distance");
                                        break;
                                }
                                return true;
                            }
                        });
                        popup.show();

                }
                return false;
            }

        });
        lvAvlFood = rootview.findViewById(R.id.list_avl_food);

        arrListAvlFood = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String >>();
        arrListLoc = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        return rootview;
    }

    private void sortAvailableFood(String by) {
        switch (by){
            case"Time":
                break;
            case"Qty":case"Qty":
                Collections.sort(arrListAvlFood, new Comparator<HashMap<String, String>>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(HashMap<String, String> obj1, HashMap<String, String> obj2) {
                        if( Double.parseDouble(obj1.get(AvailableFood.KEY_QTY)) > Double.parseDouble(obj2.get(AvailableFood.KEY_QTY)) ) {
                            return 1;
                        }
                        else {
                            return 0;
                        }
                    }
                });
                AvlFoodAdapter sortedAdapter = new AvlFoodAdapter(getActivity(),arrListAvlFood);
                lvAvlFood.setAdapter(sortedAdapter);

                break;
            case"Rating":
                break;
            case"Distance":
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

**LoadAllFood.java**

```
class LoadAllFood extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            String ngoId = new SessionManager(getContext()).getUserId();
            if(ngoId != null || !ngoId.equals("")) {
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("n_id", ngoId));
            }
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_avl_food, "GET", params);

            try {
                int success = json.getInt("success");

                if (success == 1) {

                    jaAvlFood = json.getJSONArray("avl_food");

                    // looping through All Food
                    for (int i = 0; i < jaAvlFood.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = jaAvlFood.getJSONObject(i);


                        String prep_time = c.getString("prep_time");
                        String upload_time = c.getString("upload_time");
                        Double qty = c.getDouble("qty");
                        resName = c.getString("res_name");
                        String lat = c.getString("lat");
                        String longi = c.getString("longi");
                        String rating = c.getString("g_rating");

                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        HashMap<String, String> hmLatLong = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        map.put("f_id", f_id);


                        map.put("prep_time",prep_time);
                        map.put("upload_time",upload_time);
                        map.put("qty",qty.toString());
                        map.put("name",resName);
                        map.put("g_rating", rating);


                        hmLatLong.put("lat",lat);
                        hmLatLong.put("longi",longi);

                        arrListAvlFood.add(map);
                        arrListLoc.add(hmLatLong);
                    }
                } else {

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
    }  
}
```

Comment: My suggestion is to use custom class for _Comparator_  and apply your logic there. And use your custom class for sorting.

Comment: Why not just use recyclerview?

Comment: Can you tell what is wrong with this code? Why is this not working? I have also edited my code.

Comment: You should use Model representation for your `AvailableFood` class. This will be much cleaner and easier to understand and you will also benefit from that implementation because then you will be able to sort the list according to `The time of food preparation` and other criteria, which will be the data member of your `AvailableFood` class.

Comment: @ravi Can you hint more about the Model class? Or can you resolve what's wrong with what I have done so far. I have debugged by application, the collections.sort method does not hit any breakpoint.

Comment: @DIVYARATHOD Please look at my answer below and lets discuss  there as to how you will benefit more from just using one POJO Class to model your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a model class for `Food` which will enclose other data members and also make your code much readable.

```
 class Food {
    Integer foodId;
    String preparedAt;
    String uploadedAt;
    String name;
    // other data members

    //constructor


    //setter for food id
    public setFoodId(id){
        this.foodId = id
    }
    //getter for food id
    public getFoodId(){
        return this.foodId
    }


    //setters and getters for other data members

    //toString() method
}
```

Next up in your AsyncTask for `LoadAllFoods` you can do something like:

```
class LoadAllFood extends AsyncTask<Food, String, String>{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Food... foods) {

    }
}
```

Now all you would need for your listview is a `List<Food>` and you can reference the value of `preparedAt` or any other data member on your adapter class doing something like: `food.getFoodId();`

Comment: Thanks. It is working. and the older code is working as well.